# No finite abelian group can be made into a non-zero $\Bbb Q$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the following proposition:

[image]

I understand the proof, but I don't get the conclusion. Specifically what is the relationship between $G$ being a $\Bbb Q$-module and the tensor product $G \otimes_\Bbb Z \Bbb Q$ being zero?

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: As @Shaun says. using pictures where you could just as easily use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is not a good idea on MSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the scalar multiplication operation $G \times \Bbb{Q} \to G$ of a (right-)$\Bbb{Q}$ module is balanced (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules), it factors through $G \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q}$. Hence if the latter is $\{0\}$ then $G$ must be the trivial $\Bbb{Q}$-module.

A more elementary way to see that a non-trivial finite abelian group cannot be made into a $\Bbb{Q}$-module is to note that a $\Bbb{Q}$-module is the same thing as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$ and a non-trivial vector space over an infinite field must be infinite (because if $v$ is any non-zero element, the map $q \mapsto vq$ for $q \in \Bbb{Q}$ is injective).

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is an abelian group and $\mathbb F$ is a field, then $A$ is an $\mathbb F$-vector space precisely when it has an action of $\mathbb F$ by scalar multiplication, and this is just a $\mathbb Z$-bilinear map  a $\mathbb Z$-bilinear map
$$
a\colon \mathbb F\times A \to A.
$$

Any such map is the composition of the canonical map $m\colon \mathbb F\times A \to \mathbb F\otimes_{\mathbb Z} A$ with a homomorphism of abelian groups $\tilde{a}\colon \mathbb F\otimes_{\mathbb Z} A\to A$, and conversely any homomorphism $\mathbb F\otimes_{\mathbb Z} A \to A$ gives $A$ the structure of an $\mathbb F$-vector space.

But if $\mathbb F= \mathbb Q$, then both $A$ and $\mathbb Q$ have a unique $\mathbb Z$-module structure (see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4793487/1155637) and if $A$ is finite so that $d = |A|\in \mathbb Z_{>0}$, then Lagrange's theorem shows that, for all $a\in A$ we have $d.a=0$. But then for any $a \in A$ we have
$$
\frac{m}{n}\otimes a = (\frac{m}{nd}.d)\otimes a = \frac{m}{nd}\otimes da = \frac{m}{nd}\otimes 0 = 0.
$$
hence as $\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}$ is spanned by $\frac{m}{n}\otimes a$ it follows that $\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}A = 0$. But then the scalar multiplication map $a = \tilde{a}\circ m$ must be the zero map, and this is only possible if $A=\{0\}$, since we must have $1.a =a$ for all $a \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Applying $\otimes_{\mathbb Z}D$ is how you "make" a $D$-module from an abelian group.
In particular, if the abelian group $T$ is already a $D$-module, then this "making" does nothing, i.e.,  $T\otimes_{\mathbb Z}D$ is just $T$ itself (by canonical isomorphism).

In particular every finite $\mathbb Q$-module $G$ satsifies $G=G\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q=0$.

Comment: Just to be clear, if there is a structure of $D$-vector space on $T$, that structure induces a canonical isomorphism from $T\otimes_{\mathbb Z} D$ to $T$. That is, this is not saying that there is a canonical isomorphism $T\otimes_{\mathbb Z} D\to T$ but rather every $D$-vector space structure on $T$ has a canonical isomorphism associated to it. (If $D$ is not $\mathbb Q$ (or $\mathbb F_p$) and $T\neq \{0\}$, then $D$-vector space structures on $T$ are not unique if they exist).